# Html CSS form changing background

Tags: html, css

Im making this webpage and I am almost done its just I have a question regarding the background because the second one is the one that its supposed to look like and the first one is mine. I just want to get rid of that white space in between and have like outer padding. Ive tried playing around with padding and it didnt work for some reason heres the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmjID.jpg) also heres my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cycling Tours</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            form {

                width: 700px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
            }
            fieldset {
                background-color: #4681A4;
                min-width: 700px;
                max-width: 700px;
                border: solid white 2px;
            }
            legend {
                color: white;
                text-indent: 2em;

            }
            label {
                font-size: 0.9em;
            }


            textarea {
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                height: 100px;
                min-width: 50%;
                max-width: 90%;
            }

            .buttonstyle {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color:#FFFFE6;
            }

            input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=phonenumber] {
                background-color:#ffffe6;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Fall 2018 Reviews</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/showit.pl">

            <!--<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="Donation Form">
            <input type="hidden" name="windowname" value="Donation">-->

            <fieldset id="aboutyou">
                <legend>About you(optional)</legend>
                <label for="aboutyou">I usually prefer to trips around this time of year(select all that apply)</label>
                <br>
                <select name="seasons" id="seasons" size="4" multiple>
                    <option>Winter</option>
                    <option>Spring</option>
                    <option>Summer</option>
                    <option>Fall</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" >
                <br>
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
                <br>
                <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="123-456-7890" size="12">
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" size="40">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Trip Reviews</legend>
                <div id="trails">
                    <label for="trailchoice"></label>
                    <select name="trailchoice" id="trailchoice">
                        <option value="Alberta Rural">Alberta Rural</option>
                        <option value="B.C. Coast">B.C. Coast</option>
                        <option value="Ontario Lake Superior">Ontario Lake Superior</option>
                        <option value="PEI">PEI</option>
                        <option value="Nova Scotia Cabot Trail">Nova Scotia Cabot Trail</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="daylength">
                    <label for="days"></label>
                    <select name="days" id="days">
                        <option value="5 days">5 days</option>
                        <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
                        <option value="10 days">10 days</option>
                        <option value="14 days">14 days</option>
                    </select>
                <div id="credit">
                    <input type="radio"  id="fourstars" value="4" checked>
                    <label for="fourstars"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="threestars" id="threestars" value="3">
                    <label for="threestarts"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="twostars" id="twostars" value="2">
                    <label for="twostars"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="onestar" id="onestar" value="1">
                    <label for="onestar"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
                    <br>
                    <label for="feedback">comments</label>
                    <textarea name="feedback" id="feedback" rows="6" cols="45" placeholder="Place feedback here..."></textarea>
                </div>

                    </select>

                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="fsfeedback">
                <legend>I would be interested in these trips:(check all that apply)</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Sea or Lake Coast" id="SLC" value="Sea or Lake coast">
                <label for="SLC">Sea or lake coast</label>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Rural" id="Rural" value="Rural">
                <label for="Rural">Rural</label>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Mountain" id="Mountain" value="Mountains">
                <label for="Mountain">Mountains</label>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" value="other">
                <label for="other" >Other (Please Specify)</label><label for="other"></label>
                <input type="text" name="specified" id="specified">
            </fieldset>


            <input type="submit" value="Send Review" class="buttonstyle">
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="buttonstyle">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to get rid of the white spaces between the fieldsets vertically?

Comment: @Osakr Yes and I also want to give it that space on the outside too as seen in the second picture on the imgur link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form {
  background: #4681A4;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  border: solid white 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

legend {
  color: white;
  text-indent: 2em;
}

label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.buttonstyle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FFFFE6;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=phonenumber] {
  background-color: #ffffe6;
}

.buttons {
  margin-left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fall 2018 Reviews</h1>

<form method="POST" action="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/showit.pl">

  <!--<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="Donation Form">
          <input type="hidden" name="windowname" value="Donation">-->

  <fieldset id="aboutyou">
    <legend>About you(optional)</legend>
    <label for="aboutyou">I usually prefer to trips around this time of year(select all that apply)</label>
    <br>
    <select name="seasons" id="seasons" size="4" multiple>
      <option>Winter</option>
      <option>Spring</option>
      <option>Summer</option>
      <option>Fall</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <br>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    <br>
    <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="123-456-7890" size="12">
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" size="40">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Trip Reviews</legend>
    <div id="trails">
      <label for="trailchoice"></label>
      <select name="trailchoice" id="trailchoice">
        <option value="Alberta Rural">Alberta Rural</option>
        <option value="B.C. Coast">B.C. Coast</option>
        <option value="Ontario Lake Superior">Ontario Lake Superior</option>
        <option value="PEI">PEI</option>
        <option value="Nova Scotia Cabot Trail">Nova Scotia Cabot Trail</option>
      </select>
      <div id="daylength">
        <label for="days"></label>
        <select name="days" id="days">
          <option value="5 days">5 days</option>
          <option value="7 days">7 days</option>
          <option value="10 days">10 days</option>
          <option value="14 days">14 days</option>
        </select>
        <div id="credit">
          <input type="radio" id="fourstars" value="4" checked>
          <label for="fourstars"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img
              src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="threestars" id="threestars" value="3">
          <label for="threestarts"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="twostars" id="twostars" value="2">
          <label for="twostars"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="onestar" id="onestar" value="1">
          <label for="onestar"><img src="l5mg/wheel_sm.jpg"></label>
          <br>
          <label for="feedback">comments</label>
          <textarea name="feedback" id="feedback" rows="6" cols="45" placeholder="Place feedback here..."></textarea>
        </div>

        </select>

      </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="fsfeedback">
    <legend>I would be interested in these trips:(check all that apply)</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sea or Lake Coast" id="SLC" value="Sea or Lake coast">
    <label for="SLC">Sea or lake coast</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Rural" id="Rural" value="Rural">
    <label for="Rural">Rural</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mountain" id="Mountain" value="Mountains">
    <label for="Mountain">Mountains</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" value="other">
    <label for="other">Other (Please Specify)</label><label for="other"></label>
    <input type="text" name="specified" id="specified">
  </fieldset>


  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Review" class="buttonstyle">
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="buttonstyle">
  </div>

</form>
```